# Why open the go build's binary file with vim, I can see some source repositories info?

Tags: go, go-build

In windows, new go file: `test.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

Then run `go build test.go` and then `vim test.exe`.

Search `test.go`, I can see many dir infos.

Why it happens and how to hide the info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why it happens ?

The golang is a compiled language - that's mean it uses compiler (translators that generate machine code from source code). The `test.exe` file is a source code compiled into [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code).

> How to hide the info?

The binary file (compiled program) contains all data(the source code, the `.data` section, strings and so on), you can't hide that info from binary, there is no way to do that, all that you can do is [`obfuscate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) somehow your source code.